# svn: error while loading shared libraries: libserf-1.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: svn, shared-libraries

I compiled svn 1.8.5 with serf enabled.

`./configure --prefix=/home/user/Downloads/svn --with-editor=/home/user/Downloads/vim74-install/bin/vim  --with-openssl --with-serf=$HOME/Downloads/serf_install && make && make install`

Then svn complained:

`svn: error while loading shared libraries: libserf-1.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

The `libserf-1.so.1` (and the file it points to) is indeed there

`$ll $HOME/Downloads/serf_install/lib/libserf-1.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user group 18 Feb 22 12:50 /home/user/Downloads/serf_install/lib/libserf-1.so.1 -> libserf-1.so.1.3.0
$ll /home/user/Downloads/serf_install/lib/libserf-1.so.1.3.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user group 128441 Feb 22 12:50 /home/user/Downloads/serf_install/lib/libserf-1.so.1.3.0`

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that by default, the absolute path to any dynamically linked libraries in non-standard locations is not included in the final build. Assuming you are using Linux and gcc, you can either

- fix the problem at compile time by passing additional flags to the linker to store the full path: prefix the configure command above with `LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,$HOME/Downloads/serf_install/lib"./configure...`, or
- fix the problem at runtime by executing `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/Downloads/serf_install/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"` before each use of svn or by adding it to your `.bashrc` file

The former solution is of course preferred, since it solves the problem at its root instead of providing band-aid.

Comment: I also use this solution for libsvn_ra_local-1.so.0 error by export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib

Answer (score 1):

Issue got resolved by adding,
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${SVN_HOME}/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

in .profile file of the user.